# What's the Pythonic way to iterate over two consecutive rows in a dataframe of Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to iterate over a dataframe records, as the following pseudo-code:

```
for index, row in records.iterrows():
    process(row[index-1]['Expected Time'], row[index]['Actual Time'])
```

Where `process` is a function with the logic of comparing the current record's "Actual Time" and the previous row's "Expected Time".

The above code would not work, as the row as tuple would not allow access by string with space. Instead, I have to use the index of the columns/fields for those with names containing space. 
Which is kind of hard code, not very maintainable.

I wonder if there is a better solution?

Alternatively, could it possible to iterate over a pair of dataframe, as the following pseudo-code:

```
current_df = records[1:]
previous_df = records[:-1]

for current_record, previous_record in (current_df, previous_df):
    process(previous_record['Expected Time'], current_record['Actual Time'])
```

With the same dataframe, one with the first removed, and another with the last row removed. It makes the comparison of the current row and its previous row at the same index.

How can I achieve the above in Python?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
records["prev"]=records["Expected Time"].shift(1)
records[["prev", "Actual Time"]].apply(lambda X: process(X["prev"], X["Actual Time"]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Exactly of what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on what your process function looks like you can go a lot faster. Take a look at numpy.vectorize. It can be much faster than apply.


https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html